# How do I stop the backgroundworker when the messagebox exits?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, messagebox

I'm designing a form in C #. I use backgroundworker to perform my operations in the form I designed. and messagebox.show () is output at the end of the transaction; And I have to go to the next step. But backgorundworker continues to work despite the message box. Backgroundworker probably need to fill in the RunWorkerCompleted method. but as the message box sees, I don't know how to stop it from working.
Can you help me? I think;

```
if(MessageBox.Show("convert is okey")
{
    ....//but ı dont know what am ı writing here, too?
}
```

Background worker is:

```
private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();      
   backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true; 
}

private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
    { 
        Convert(); backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i); 
    } 
    // Bitrate(); 
} // is do work

private void BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; 
}

private void BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    progressBar1.Value = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to give us a bit more of your code to understand the problem

Comment: Okay, I'm doing a converter operation. I used the backgroundworker because I used it in the progress bar during the process. When the process is finished, I get an error like backgroundworker is working now when I want to convert again with different values in the form. I know the process is over. Viddeo caonverter; I can observe in the file and I can give a warning that it ends with message box. But when my convert is finished, the backgroundworker should stop running until the next one is triggered. @Steve

Comment: Good description, but clearly something is not as you think. Code?

Comment: Backgroundworker is'  private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }'

Comment: private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
          
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Convert();

                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            }
            // Bitrate();
           
        } // is do work

Comment: private void BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        }

Comment: private void BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;

        }
and this;

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable that can be accessed by both the background worker and UI code. To be simple lets keep it as a public static variable.

```
public class YourClass
{
   public static bool IsBackgroundProcessActive = true;
}
```

Now when you work with the message box change that variable.

```
if(MessageBox.Show("convert is okey")
{
    yourClass.IsBackgroundProcessActive  = false;
}
```

Now you need to make the background worker listen to this variable.
For most common cases this background worker will be a loop with a simple process. So you can set the loop condition to check this variable,

```
private void YourBackgroundWorkerFunction()
{
    while(yourClass.IsBackgroundProcessActive)
    {
       // Your simple iterative task 
    }
}
```

For complex cases where the background worker is not a simple loop, you can use an exception to stop the thread. For that case write a simple function as,

```
private void MarkAsSafeToStop()
{
    if(!yourClass.IsBackgroundProcessActive)
    {
        throw new OperationCancelledException();
    }
}
```

Then use this function in several places of your background worker function. Then the background worker will stop with an exception whenever you reach this function after clicking the message box.

ie

```
private void YourBackgroundWorkerFunction()
{
   // Some code
   MarkAsSafeToStop();
   // Some other code
   MarkAsSafeToStop();
   // and so on.
}
```

Comment: Yes ı did but ı have error like this;                           cannot implicitly convert type 'Ssytem.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to bool.            if ı used to if(messagebox("convert is okey") like this, ı have error

Comment: oopz my bad.
Your problem is about type converting.
Just use if(MessageBox.Show("convert is okey") == DialogResult.OK){} And every thing will be fine.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.'
 foult is this! I take the again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt cancellation mechanism built in background worker.

https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/cancelling-the-backgroundworker/